# Double integration when D: $x^2 + y^2 \le R^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am getting ready for my calculus exam and I encountered a double integral which is defined in a strange area:

\begin{align}
\iint_{D}\:(x^2+y^2)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \quad \text{where}\quad    
D: x^2+y^2 \le R^2, y\geq 0
\end{align}

How the graph of integration would look for such an area?

Comment: It's an integral of $r^3$ over half a circle. What do you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $x^2+y^2 = R^2$ is the equation of a circle with radius $R$, the inequality is the closed circle with radius $R$. Combined with the condition $y\geq0$ we see that $D$ is the upper half circle.

Comment: I feel so stupid now, even for asking this question. Thank you :)